# Datetime concate with string

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I want to simplify this and use it as a starttime parameter.

```
let d=  format_datetime(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
let t= "T10:00:00.000Z";  
let str= strcat(d,t);
let dt= todatetime(str); 
print dt
```

5/6/2020, 10:00:00.000 AM

I always want to return today's yyyy-MM-dd but hard code the time

The way I have done it works but I'm hoping there's a better way

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better variant would be avoiding string creation and parsing, and using datetime arithmetic operations instead:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions#datetimetimespan-functions

```
let dt = startofday(now())+10h;
print dt
```

Comment: Perfect! and thanks for the link. I had no idea that function existed